# Deploying C++ solution using VS2010

Tags: c++, .net, deployment, installation, exe

I've tried this tutorial, but couldn't make it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384837.aspx

After installing set up, when I tried to run the exe file, it doesn't respond and error occurs.

The error message is:

> Invalid Command-line parameters. Unable to continue

Is there any other way to run an application on another computer?

Comment: You need to provide the exact error message. And what do you mean by running the application on another computer?

Comment: @Hippo I edit the question and add the error message..

Comment: @Dervall I editted the question and add the error message.

Comment: Does your package have an EXE bootstrapper or is it just the MSI? Does the error occur when launching the MSI directly?